# JQUERY Selector not working on multiple ids with same name

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am a newbie to JQUERY i recently wrote a small piece of code in which i am having an issue i have two  anchors with same id in page but there albid (Custom Attribute) value is different. But in this case jquery function works on only first  anchor not on second one.
Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#test").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("test.php?"+$("#test").attr("albid"));
});
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<a albid="12" id="test"/>hasnain</a>
<a albid="2" id="test" />naanan</a>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

How can i fix this issue
Thanks you

Comment: ID  s *should* be unique. Use `class` or `data-*` attributes instead. Also, your `<a>` cannot end like `/>`

Comment: You can't use an exact same id within the same HTML code. As you have used the same id `test` more than once, JavaScript/jQuery can only take the first one. It will not look for another `test` on your HTML as an `id` should be unique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

> **id selector**
>
> Description: Selects a single element with the given id attribute.

If you wish to select multiple elements, you could give them all the same `class="test"` and then use:

```
$(".test").click(function(){
  $("#div1").load("test.php?" + $(this).attr("albid"));
});
```

Note the use of `$(this)` inside the function.

Comment: Might suggest the use of data attributes instead of custom attributes but +1